# How to print next letters until Z and continue to A?

Tags: c++, algorithm, printing, stdstring, alphabet

This code prints the next letters of what I input.
For example, I input "`v`", it will show `vwxyz`, but I want it to print the others too, like `vwxyzabc.....`

```
int main()
{
   char a;
   int flag = 0;
   scanf("%c", &a);

   while (a <= 'z') 
   {
      printf("%c", a);
      a++;
   }

   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

I am new to c++, can someone help me?

Comment: Hint: You're going to need another loop.

Comment: Or one loop that loops 26 times, some addition and modulo.

Comment: What is your stopping criteria? How many times do you want to loop through the alphabet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the incremented character is not an alphabet, deduct `26` to go back to the starting and do the loop until you see the entered character.

```
#include <cctype> // std::isalpha

char curr = a;
do
{
   printf("%c", curr);
   ++curr;
   if (!std::isalpha(static_cast<unsigned char>(curr)))
      curr -= 26;

} while (curr != a);
```

**([See live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FDsgCI24DFtbn1e8))**